# Ajax.BeginForm doesn't work properly

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with `Ajax submit`. I have a main `View` where I render a `PartialView` and inside the last one I load another `PartialView`. Something like this:

- Main view

  - List of elements                  -> `PartialView` 1

    - Create new element  -> `PartialView` 2 inside `PartialView` 1

I am using `AjaxBeginForm` with replace and update options:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", 
      new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "form0", HttpMethod = "POST" }))
```

My problem is that submit works very well first time. It saves the new element and re-render the `PartialView` 1 ( it updates my list ). If want to submit again it will redirect me to `PartialView` 1.

Why is happening that and what is wrong in my code? How can I do it ?

Here's my **controller action**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Create(Model viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.Save(viewModel.FormModel);

        var newViewModel = new DefaultViewModel(viewModel.xID,viewModel.yID);

        return PartialView("_DefaultPartialView", newViewModel);

    }
```

It's ok my action returns a `PartialView`? It should be of type `JsonResult` ?

And **`PartialView` 1**:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateBehaviorLog", "BehaviorLog", new AjaxOptions {    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "form0", HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{

@model DefaultViewModel

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<h2>Title</h2>

 { Html.RenderPartial("PartialView2",    Model.ModelForPartialView2); }

<div id="listOfELements">

 @foreach(var item in Model.X)
  {
     --list--
  }  
</div>
}
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I fixed this ( it was a very newbie mistake ). I'll post tomorrow my answer because now it's kinda late and I need to sleep!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first of all, when you make an Ajax call be sure you included everything you need. Here I mean:

- Be sure to have `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled"
  value="true"/>` in your webconfig.
- Be sure you have included the script in the page.
- If you are using the latest `jQuery` you need to change `live` function with `on` in your `unobtrusive script`.

Btw, if you have the problem mentioned above here is what I have done first time ( it is changed now because it's not such a good solution ) :

```
 MainView

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", 
  new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "form0", HttpMethod = "POST" }))
    {
     RenderPartial1

         RenderPartial1.2
     }


     RenderPartial2
     ..
     RenderPartialN
```

As you can see, I've put `AjaxBeginForm` outside the `Partial1.2` from which I `submit`, in the `MainView`. This method wasn't so good because if you need 2 forms what will you do then ?

In the end I quit using `AjaxBeginForm` and used `HtmlBeginForm` with `ajax post` from `javascript`.

Comment: Unobtrusive wasn't included in my case.