# MVC AJAX form in PartialView posts to ajax first time, second time does full post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm getting an issue where the first time I post my form it uses ajax and updates, but the second it does a full post back and replaces the page with my partial view. I've checked that I have `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true` and have replaced `live` with `on` on my unobtrusive script... still have the same issue.

UPDATE: Only happens when the ModelState is not valid.

This is the closes I've come to finding an answer but still didn't fix it:
[Ajax.BeginForm doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926818/ajax-beginform-doesnt-work-properly/14952542#14952542)

Any light you can shine on this will be appreciated.

This is my main view (Tester):

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "testView";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    My TestView</h2>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_Form", new Project.Models.TestModel());}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

This is my partial view form (_Form):

```
@model Project.Models.TestModel
<div class="updatable">
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("TestProjUpdate")" data-site-ajax="true" data-site-target=".updatable">
<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TextField)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TextField)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TextField)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Tester()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult TesterProjUpdate(TestModel model)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return PartialView("_Form", model);

    TestProj.Vehicle vehicle = new TestProj.Vehicle();

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_Vehicle", vehicle);
    }

    return PartialView("_Form", model);

}
```

and finally my jQuery ajax call:

```
$(function () {

var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize(),
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-site-target"));
        $target.replaceWith(data);
    });

    return false;
};

$("form[data-site-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
```

});

Any help you can give me will be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your

```
$("form[data-site-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
```

to

```
$("form[data-site-ajax='true']").one('submit', ajaxFormSubmit);
```

then after your $target.replaceWith(data); add

```
$("form[data-site-ajax='true']").one('submit', ajaxFormSubmit);
```